# Convert OpenGL 3D point to 2D using GLU.glProject

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, 2d, perspective

I have an OpenGL scene with a sphere having a radius of 1, and the camera being at the center of the sphere (it's a 360° picture viewer). The user can rotate the sphere by panning.

Now I need to display 2D pins "attached" to some parts of the picture. To do so, I want to convert the 3D coordinates of my pins into 2D screen coordinates, to add the pin image at that screen coordinates.

I'm using GLU.glProject and the following classes from [android-apidemo](https://github.com/appium/android-apidemos/tree/master/src/io/appium/android/apis/graphics/spritetext):

- MatrixGrabber
- MatrixStack
- MatrixTrackingGL

I save the projection matrix in the onSurfaceChanged method and the model-view matrix in the onDraw method (after having drawn my sphere). Then I feed GLU.glProject with them when the user rotates the sphere to update the pins position.

When I pan horizontally, the pins pan correctly, but when I pan vertically, the texture pans "faster" than the pin image (like if the pin was closer to the camera than the sphere).

Here are some relevant parts of my code:

```
public class CustomRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    MatrixGrabber mMatrixGrabber = new MatrixGrabber();
    private float[] mModelView = null;
    private float[] mProjection = null;

    [...]

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        // Get the sizes:
        float side = Math.max(width, height);
        int x = (int) (width - side) / 2;
        int y = (int) (height - side) / 2;

        // Set the viewport:
        gl.glViewport(x, y, (int) side, (int) side);

        // Set the perspective:
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, FIELD_OF_VIEW_Y, 1, Z_NEAR, Z_FAR);

        // Grab the projection matrix:
        mMatrixGrabber.getCurrentProjection(gl);
        mProjection = mMatrixGrabber.mProjection;

        // Set to MODELVIEW mode:
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        // Load the texture if needed:
        if(mTextureToLoad != null) {

            mSphere.loadGLTexture(gl, mTextureToLoad);
            mTextureToLoad = null;
        }

        // Clear:
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // Rotate the scene:
        gl.glRotatef( (1 - mRotationY + 0.25f) * 360, 1, 0, 0); // 0.25 is used to adjust the texture position
        gl.glRotatef( (1 - mRotationX + 0.25f) * 360, 0, 1, 0); // 0.25 is used to adjust the texture position

        // Draw the sphere:
        mSphere.draw(gl);

        // Grab the model-view matrix:
        mMatrixGrabber.getCurrentModelView(gl);
        mModelView = mMatrixGrabber.mModelView;
    }

    public float[] getScreenCoords(float x, float y, float z) {

        if(mModelView == null || mProjection == null) return null;

        float[] result = new float[3];
        int[] view = new int[] {0, 0, (int) mSurfaceViewSize.getWidth(), (int) mSurfaceViewSize.getHeight()};

        GLU.gluProject(x, y, z,
                mModelView, 0,
                mProjection, 0,
                view, 0,
                result, 0);

        result[1] = mSurfaceViewSize.getHeight() - result[1];

        return result;
    }
}
```

I use the result of the getScreenCoords method to display my pins. The y value is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is a "pin" here? Is that an image which is always facing the camera?

Comment: Yep, a 2D picture. I probably have a solution now (but other problems to fix), I'll try to post it later.

Comment: Try searching `OpenGL ES billboards' then. I would suggest you using point sprites if you were using OpenGL ES 2 but it seems you are using ES 1 which doesn't support them. There's an extension though, called [OES_point_sprite](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_point_sprite.txt).